# Help us call for proposals for the SE Fellowship on your blog, site or listserv

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

The [SE Research Support and Fellowship Program](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/202/344) launched recently with our very own experienced and highly respected users reviewing fellowship applications.

To make the program a success, we need your help. Announce the program and request for proposals on your blog, website or listserv.

Please let us know (academics@stackexchange.com) if you intend to call for applications so we can follow your announcement.